# Blog images are acting strange

Tags: wordpress, magento, cpanel

I have Mangento Wordpress integration in my webshop and the blog [images](http://www.genuinelyjanestudios.com/genuinelyblog/) aren't being loaded, i tried changing the permissions of folders but it didn't work. Tried a lot of research on this problem but turns out no is having it. Even when i upload the pictures using media uploader it shows up like [this](http://screencast.com/t/YDlFn0thfw) (the picture doesn't show) and when click insert, it insert a broken image icon.

Answer (score 0):

Have you uploaded images in correct path as per your website coding, The most issues related to images is that images doesn't exists in their path location that is mentioned in code. You should check the error logs for the same.

Comment: php logs? or which logs? the path is right as i upload the picture when it gives me blank image.

Comment: Then the issue only can rectify from logs, check apache logs in location /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log and /usr/local/apache/logs/access_log.

Comment: i saw it under logs in my shared cpanel account and it doesn't have any error. how ever the system.log in var/logs have [these](http://pastebin.aquilenet.fr/?499c86f49b610fc1#xyk/hF+nTxttrIZsJaCVTOiOo/VFp32+jWwYAz8Vqzs=) errors and wordpress.log have [these](http://pastebin.aquilenet.fr/?a91450230831d7a2#mgDyFKbA963hEvvm9Uw/oYinRhxyrHQlSHYzA2g9xEM=) are these helpful or should i looking somewhere else for the apache logs?

Comment: Your server is cpanel server and mostly in cpanel server apache logs location is /usr/local/apache/logs/
but in plain server it is /var/logs/httpd/. You can check your logs for image as below:

>grep image-name /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log

or 

>grep image-name /usr/local/apache/logs/access_log

Replace image-name with your image's name